# Points of intersection of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the points of intersection of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$. I've tried but I keep getting 4 solutions... Would someone please be able to take me through the process?

I squared $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ and then got $\sin x = \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{2}}$
which gave the solutions $\pi\over 4$, $3\pi \over 4$, $5\pi \over 4$ and $7\pi\over 4$.

Comment: Would you please show your work? (Take a picture if you have to if you're having trouble writing it up.) Sometimes when you're doing algebraic problems you end up getting "spurious" solutions that solve some equation you obtained later on down the line but are not actually solutions to the original equation. This happens when you square an equation, for instance.

Comment: Which four do you get?

Comment: Thanks for editing to add your solutions! Why don't you try plugging each of the four of those into your original equation to see if *all* of them solve it? (A simpler way to do this problem is to use the fact that $\sin x = \cos x$ gives that $\tan x = 1$.)

Comment: hint: given and angle $x$ there corresponds a point on the unit circle whose coordinates are $(\cos x, \sin x)$. Where are the horizontal and vertical components equal to each other?

Answer (score 4):

$\sin x = \cos x \implies \sin^2x = \cos^2 x $ together with the proviso that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ must share the same sign.

So the only two solutions are

$\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $\cos x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ giving $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

and

$\sin x=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}$, $\cos x=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}$ giving $x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions. $$\sin x = \cos x \Rightarrow \tan x = 1$$
because clearly $\cos x \neq 0$ so we can divide both sides by $\cos x$.

Therefore, when $x \in [0,2\pi]$, the solutions are $x_1 = \frac{1}{4}\pi$ and $x_2 = \frac{5}{4}\pi$.

Here is the [figure](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sinx+and+cosx+from+0+to+2pi).

Edit: When you square both sides, you will make $(-\sin x)^2 = (\sin x)^2$. If $-\sin x = \cos x$, their squares are equal, which is a problem since they are not $0$.